# Question about ".*" in match regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

Following is a simple piece of code about regex match:

```
import re

pattern = ".*"
s = "ab"
print(re.search(pattern, s))
```

output:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='ab'>
```

My confusion is  `"."` matches any single character, so here it's able to match `"a"` or `"b"` , then with a `"*"` behind it, this combo should be able to match `""` `"a"` or `"aa"` or `"aaa..."` or `"b"` or `"bb"` or `"bbb..."` or other single characters that repeat for several times.

But how comes it(`".*"`) matches "ab" the same time?

Comment: Search term: regex greediness

Comment: You've misunderstood. The dot matches any character. ".*", then, matches any character, specifically 0 or more of them. They don't have to be the same character.

Comment: To add to what @user10987432 said, you seem to be looking for `(.)?\1*`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/WikflG/1).

Comment: @user10987432 well, this make sense.I still got little confused about it, but it explains reasonablly. Thanks .

Answer (score -1):

The comments more or less covered it, but to provide an answer: the pattern `.*` means to match any character `.` zero or more times `*`. And by default, a regex is greedy so when presented with `'abc'`, even though `''` would satisfy that rule, or `'a'` would, etc., it will match the entire string, since matching all of it still meets the requirement.

It does *not* mean to match the same character zero or more times. Every character it matches can be a different character or the same as a previously matched one.

If instead you want to match any character, but match as many of that same character as possible, zero or more times, you can use:

```
(.)?\1*
```

See here https://regex101.com/r/FgvuX2/1 and here https://regex101.com/r/FgvuX2/2

What this effectively does, is match a single character optionally, creating a back reference which can be used in the second part of the expression. Thus it matches any single character (if there is one) to group 1 and matches that group 1 zero or more times, being greedy.